# pubnub history api call always returning timetoken

Tags: javascript, react-native, pubnub

I'm using the pubnub api in my react native app and making a call to get message history as follows:

```
pubnub.history({
  channel: channel,
  count: 15,
  includeTimetoken: false,
  start: props.lastMessageTimestamp
},
function(status, response){
  console.log(response);
  if (!status.error){
    props.addHistory(response);
  }
}
);
```

For some reason I'm always getting the timetoken returned with each message. By default and even if I specify not to return the timetoken. Any idea what's going on here? Here's a sample response:

```
{ messages: 
   { messages: 
      [ { timetoken: null,
          entry: 
           { text: 'This is a message',
             user: { _id: 1 },
             createdAt: '2016-10-25T18:56:50.205Z',
             _id: 'temp-id-958468' } },
        { timetoken: null,
          entry: 
           { text: 'Message',
             user: { _id: 1 },
             createdAt: '2016-10-25T18:57:45.810Z',
             _id: 'temp-id-322242' } },
        { timetoken: null,
          entry: 
           { text: 'Test',
             user: { _id: 1 },
             createdAt: '2016-10-25T21:25:43.290Z',
             _id: 'temp-id-806299' } },
        { timetoken: null,
          entry: 
           { text: 'Text',
             user: { _id: 1 },
             createdAt: '2016-10-25T21:34:41.204Z',
             _id: 'temp-id-399187' } } ],
     startTimeToken: 14774207865431668,
     endTimeToken: 14774312812443264 },
  timestamp: undefined }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub History Timetokens

This is by design - the new SDK v4 response payload always returns the `timetoken` key it just doesn't have a value if `includeTimetoken` is false (the default), but probably not necessary to ever exclude the timetokens so we'll probably just deprecate `includeTimetoken`.

### The Future of Storage add-on & History API

We are redesigning the Storage architecture and the `history` API to greatly enhance features and usability (ease of use) and we will be returning `timetoken` with each message by default with no option to exclude them. It's just typically something you need more than you don't.